# React Dnd useDrag is not working properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-dnd

I'm using react dnd and it's useDrag method not working properly. Let me elaborate the situation:

1. User will drag list item from left to right as stated below:
   [image]

   2. Final outcome of right side will be like this below pic,
      [image]

every list items list 1, 2, 3 will be draggable everywhere and droppable.

The list items List 1 useDrag code is :

```
const [{ isDragging }, drag, preview] = useDrag({
    item: {
      type: 'tool',
      id: id
    },
    canDrag: true,
    begin(props, monitor, component) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".rowWrapper").forEach(function(item){
        item.classList.add("rowBorder", "pd-row-drag", "mb-row-drag");
      });         
      document.querySelectorAll(".drop-area").forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.add("dropAreaPosition");
      });
      document.querySelectorAll(".rowBorderOverlay").forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.add("hideElement");
      });
      document.querySelectorAll(".rowActions").forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.add("hideElement");
      });
    },
    end(props, monitor, component) {      
      document.querySelectorAll(".rowWrapper").forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove("rowBorder", "pd-row-drag", "mb-row-drag");
      });
      document.querySelectorAll(".dropZone").forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove("showDropZone");
      });
      document.querySelectorAll(".drop-area").forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove("placeHolder","dropAreaPosition");
      });
      document.querySelectorAll(".rowActions").forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove("hideElement");
      });
    },
    collect: monitor => ({
      item: monitor.getItem(),
      isDragging: !!monitor.isDragging()
    }),
});
```

What I'm doing here is, when dragging begins I'm doing the above stuff like adding classes/removing. By doing like this, useDrag is not working properly when you drag list 1 the full container is not draggable only the portion of it.

if I remove begin, end I can drag the entire container, I  don't know what's causing the problem here ?

Any help on  this really appreciable ? or how do I do the stuff like adding classes/removing whild dragging or drag begin ?

Comment: You should provide a working example so it is easier to point out errors or understand the problem. But yes, dnd is a pain in the ... somewhere.